# Excel MATCH Function Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-match

I am trying to find a value containing "~" using the `MATCH` function, and it's returning a `#N/A` error.

See the below example. Cell `B1` returns `#N/A`:

```
    A          B
1   ~toto      =MATCH(A1,A2:A3,0)
2   ~toto
3   ~titi
```

I used the `RIGHT` function to remove the "~", and it worked.

My problem is that I have to match values such as "~toto~tata~tutu".

Has anyone any idea how to solve this?

FYI, I can't use VBA for incompatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is by using below formula

```
=MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1,A2:A3),0)
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. See image for reference.

[image]

To take care of error if no match found use array formula as

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1,A2:A3),0),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=MATCH("~"&A1,A2:A3,0)
```

`~` being a wildcard identifier may have something to do with it.

**As noted by Pnuts, this wouldn't work if the symbol `~` appears later on in the same string. Also for some reason unknown to me it gives a match for `~tutu~tata` when my lookup value is `~tutu`**

Comment: @pnuts Also noted something else. when my lookup value is `~tutu`, it gives a match for `~tutu~tata`. The use of `~` certainly requires more research by myself.

Comment: `If you want to find an actual question mark or asterisk, type a tilde (~) before the character.` This is the exact logic I had used to find the actual `~` mark for the purpose of answer. But still it doesn't explain why it shouldn't work for `~toto~tata~tutu`